# Excel 3D Reference: Delineate string results from range of Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, excel-formula

Hopefully I can explain this right.

Looking to combine cells of text strings from multiple worksheets into one master worksheet.

Basically 3-D References. But formatted into rows and columns. And referencing a range of worksheets so new worksheets can be added or removed in between the bookends.

Desired output:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WS01 Cell B1 | WS02 Cell B1 | WS03 Cell B1 |
| WS01 Cell B2 | WS02 Cell B2 | WS03 Cell B2 |
| WS01 Cell B3 | WS02 Cell B3 | WS03 Cell B3 |

Input: Strings from B1:B3 (should become matching rows separated into columns for each linked worksheet)

Each worksheet ('Worksheet 01:Worksheet 03') follows same format:

| Column B |
| --- |
| WS## Cell B1 |
| WS## Cell B2 |
| WS## Cell B3 |

Attempts:

=CONCAT('Worksheet 01:Worksheet 03'!B1:B3)

Result:

WS01 Cell B1WS01 Cell B2WS01 Cell B3WS02 Cell B1WS02 Cell B2WS02 Cell B3WS03 Cell B1WS03 Cell B2WS03 Cell B3

Please let me know what you think. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
=HSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet3!B1:B3)
```

Comment: I find I'm really getting behind on new worksheet functions... 

Comment: I was overdoing it. This is way easier. Funny how it works though..

Comment: Wow this seems to work perfectly. I can't believe there's actually a function for this, thank you.

I apologize for asking for more, but would this be able to be modified to transpose these columns to rows?

Row 1: Sheet1 B1 | Sheet1 B2 | Sheet1 B3
Row 2: Sheet2 B1 | Sheet2 B2 | Sheet2 B3...

Comment: As you say it yourself: transpose. Have you tried wrapping it in transpose()?

Comment: I think you need `=WRAPROWS(VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet3!B1:B2),2)` for that? Or possibly `TRANSPOSE()` as per P.b. @DannyWalter.

Comment: Ah, hot damn P.b it was looking me right in the face. You are correct, sir: =TRANSPOSE(HSTACK('Worksheet 01:Worksheet 03'!B2:B10))

Answer (score 3):

Even though the answer below works fine, please look at this answer by JvdV that is far easier to use:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74077560/12634230

```
=LET(
c,CONCAT(Sheet1:Sheet4!B1:B3),
q,SEQUENCE(LEN(c)/36,3,,12),
TRANSPOSE(MID(c,q,12)))
```

`c` uses your CONCAT formula to retrieve a concatenation of all values.
`q` calculates a sequence by the length of `c` divided by the length of text for the 3 values per Sheet (3* length 12 = 36) by 3 with steps of the length of each value (12).
This sequence is used in the `MID` function and needs the result to be transposed to meet your requirements:

[image]

If a Sheet will be added, changing the Sheet names in `c` will change the result to show the values from that Sheet as well. No further adjustments of the formula are required.

And if the number of outputs per sheet, or string length may change in future you could define these as variables too:

```
=LET(c,CONCAT('Worksheet 01:Worksheet 03'!B1:B3),
stringlength,12,
stringcount,3,
q,SEQUENCE(LEN(c)/(stringlength*stringcount),stringcount,,stringlength),
TRANSPOSE(MID(c,q,stringlength)))
```

Comment: Thank you P.b for taking the time to answer my question. Like you said HSTACK appears to do the trick, but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

@P.b just posted a formula approach, but as an alternative here's a VBA user-defined formula which returns an array.  The only tricky part is getting the 3D reference in the UDF, since there's no structure or type equivalent to that in VBA: if you try to get it directly from the argument you just get an error.

Building from: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/476283-user-defined-function-receiving-a-range-as-parameter.html

```vb
Function MyUDF(v)
    Dim c As Range, f, arr, arrWs, rngAddr
    Dim arrout, indx1, indx2, i As Long, r As Long, data
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set c = Application.Caller
    On Error GoTo 0
    If c Is Nothing Then
        f = "=myudf(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1:A3)" 'for testing purposes (adjust as needed)...
    Else
        f = c.Formula  'read the formula from the calling cells
    End If
    
    f = Mid(f, 8, Len(f) - 8)   'parse out the parens and formula name
    arr = Split(f, "!")         'get an array from splitting on !
    arrWs = Split(arr(0), ":")  'get the start/end worksheet names
    indx1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(arrWs(0)).Index
    indx2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(arrWs(1)).Index
    rngAddr = arr(1)            '...and the range address
    
    'size the output array
    ReDim arrout(1 To Range(rngAddr).Rows.Count, 1 To 1 + (indx2 - indx1))
    For i = indx1 To indx2      'loop over the worksheets
        data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range(rngAddr).Value
        For r = 1 To UBound(data)
            arrout(r, i) = data(r, 1)
        Next r
    Next i
    MyUDF = arrout  'return the array
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, Tim thank you so much for taking the time to respond to my question. It looks like HSTACK is working for me, but I will keep your code on hand for the future.