# #VALUE! Error Using Lambda And ByRow Helper Function in Excel (365)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I am creating a dynamic report summarizing data on multiple XLS sheets all within a single workbook. The sheets have names that tie to a specific date.

This is simplified example of what I am doing, which works fine - it gives the correct answer which is the value of the cell at reference BB38 on the sheet called "221122":

```
=LAMBDA(r,INDIRECT("'" & r & "'!BB38"))("221122")
```

Problem comes when I want to iterate this over an array of sheets using `BYROW` instead of just passing the sheet name to the lambda. Simple example to replicate the problem:

```
=BYROW({"221122"}, LAMBDA(r,INDIRECT("'" & r & "'!BB38")))
```

This gives a `#VALUE!` error, instead of the correct answer which is the reference to that same cell (as part of a one cell dynamic array result). The only way I can solve it is by adding a `SUM` around the `INDIRECT`:

```
=BYROW({"221122"}, LAMBDA(r,SUM(INDIRECT("'"&r&"'!BB38"))))
```

Apart from being ugly, what I REALLY want to do is get a group of cells (spilled) back, like this, but then I can't use the `SUM` trick:

```
=BYROW({"221120","221121","221122"}, LAMBDA(r,INDIRECT("'"&r&"'!BB38:BD38")))
```

So that I am aiming towards is a spilled range like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 221120!BB38 | 221120!BC38 | 221120!BD38 |
| 221121!BB38 | 221121!BC38 | 221121!BD38 |
| 221122!BB38 | 221122!BC38 | 221122!BD38 |

I know that you can't pass a dynamic function to `INDIRECT` but that's not what I am doing here - I am passing a single row of the dynamic array, represented by `r`.

In comment, Harun24hr points out correctly that `BYROW` can't return a dynamic array - that's why `SUM` worked. My own 'hack' way around this was to get the individual 1xN ranges of cells representing BB38, BC38 and BD38 and then `HSTACK` them together, e.g.:

```
    a, BYROW(sheets, LAMBDA(r, SUM(INDIRECT("'" & r & "'!AY38")))),
    b, BYROW(sheets, LAMBDA(r, SUM(INDIRECT("'" & r & "'!AZ38")))),
    c, BYROW(sheets, LAMBDA(r, SUM(INDIRECT("'" & r & "'!BA38")))),
    d, BYROW(sheets, LAMBDA(r, SUM(INDIRECT("'" & r & "'!BB38")))),
    HSTACK(a,b,c,d)
```

Real question is: is there a more elegant / scalable way than `HSTACK` 1xN columns together?

Any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: What is your end goal then? You just want to return the value of single cell?

Comment: What about this one `=BYROW({"221122"}, LAMBDA(r,INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & r & "'!BB38"),1,1)))`?

Comment: Using INDEX like that works, yes. But see my last example - what I really want to do is return a range of three adjacent cells, for example, 221122!BB3:BD38. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes. There is way. But after returning those 3 cells then what action you are planning to do? `BYROW()` can return single value result not array. For array output you need to use `REDUCE()` function. That is reason to know what is your actual goal. Can you simply show some input and output example?

Comment: Lets try `=REDUCE(0,{"221122"}, LAMBDA(a,b,INDIRECT("'" & b & "'!BB38:BD38")))`. If it works then let me know. I will post this as answer.

Comment: Added example at the end... Thanks.

Comment: Your right that the problem (why I needed a SUM) is because the BYROW has to return a single value, it can't return a dynamic array (even a one cell dynamic array). Same reason your INDEX approach works. So I need  a different approach than BYROW. It's not REDUCE, because that gives a single value, whereas I need (in the end) a 2D output.  My own hack was to do column by column (with the sum) and then use HSTACK to join the individual columns together. I should have said... is there a better answer than that...

Comment: `REDUCE()` can output dynamic array not single cell/value.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Will investigate, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach:

```
=LET(start,221120,
     end,221122,
DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(1+end-start,,start),LAMBDA(s,e,VSTACK(s,INDIRECT("'"&e&"'!BB38:BD38)))),1))
```

Or simple `=VSTACK('221120:221122'!BB38:BD38)` based on this answer by JvdV: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74077560/12634230

Comment: Wow - it works! Thanks. Amazing that REDUCE can actually return a dynamic array (I understood from the documentation it was just a single value). And credit to @Harun24hr for calling out the REDUCE / VSTACK idea in the comments.

Comment: Hang on - you can do ranges of sheets?!!! Two amazing answers. Tx.

Comment: It can be used to do BYROW spill formula calculations. Just keep in mind `REDUCE` always starts at it's initial value (`0` in this case) and VSTACK or HSTACK can be used to SPILL the values. DROP can be used to remove the initial value where the recalculation of it's lambda value hasn't started yet.

Comment: I thought the second option might come handy as well